# Grafana creating Group By Time Series using custom SQL Plugin

Tags: grafana

Creating a panel in Grafana using an SQL-like database and a custom data source Grafana plugin. I want to create a time series graph with multiple data points. E.g. if I have 3 columns (time, id, metric) I want a time series graph with a different line for each metric and the value being the amount of ids in that specific time.

My current query is something like

```
SELECT date_time AS 'Time', COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) AS 'value', string_field AS 'metric' FROM my_table WHERE filter='reason' AND ... GROUP BY date_time, string_field
```

This returns the data in a way I would expect:

```
|Time        | value | metric         |
|-------------------------------------|
| 2023-01-01 | 1     | example_metric |
```

However Grafana is outputting this as though the metric column didn't exist. It just outputs the 'value' amount. I want the y-axis to be the count and the label to be the 'metric' column.